# Optimize result of sql query from huge table with key value pairs

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I am currently using the below query :-

```
SELECT  /*+parallel(16)*/
    key,
    MAX(value),
    MIN(value)
FROM
    key_value
GROUP BY
    key;
```

key_value has 100 Billion records.

How can we optimise this? I am not interested to get max or min rather any random record for each key will suffice my need.

I just need a sample record for each key for some analysis.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Create a multicolum covering index on `(key,value )`

Comment: How many distinct values of `key` are there?

Comment: @TonyAndrews , Hey Tony Its about 850 , minimum count for a given key is 1 and maximum count goes to 2 Billion.

Comment: What indexes do you have that include the `key` column?

Comment: ideally , This question should be asked to the database vendor.